# Suppress yield arguments

Tags: ruby

I have a wrapper around a method that takes a block:

```
def loop &b
  [:a].each_with_index &b
end
loop{ |v,i,m| "#{v} #{i} #{m}" } #=> :a 0 nil
```

`m` returns nil because it is undefined.

Is it possible to stop `loop` from having access to `each_with_index`' second block argument, so `i` would be undefined and this would happen?

```
loop { |v,i,m| "#{v} #{i} #{m}" } #=> :a nil nil
```

Let's pretend I have access to the inner method:

```
def loop &b
  [:a].my_each &b
end
```

Is there anything I could do to yield to achieve this? My pseudo code:

```
def my_each &b
...
    yield v, supress(i)
...
end
```

This isn't a case of simply not giving `yield` `i`, however:

```
loop { |v,i| }     # DO NOT WANT ACCESS TO i HERE
def loop &b
  [:a].my_each &b  # NEED ACCESS TO i HERE
end
```

Comment: If you don't want/need to access index somewhere, then... don't [access it there]? From your desired snippet, it seems to be impossible to satisfy both needs.

Comment: Unless you're willing to do things like `loop(:need_index => true) do |v, i| `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modification of stefan answer :

```
def loop
   [:a, :b, :c].each_with_index do |v, i|
        # you have access to both, v and i here
        yield v,i
    end
end

loop do |v, i|
  # here you have v + i
  p v, i
end

loop do |v|
   # here you have only v
   # no need to take all arguments
   p v
 end
```

It's up to you what arguments you want when you specify your block.
You YIELD all arguments, then you take the ones you need INSIDE your block.

Ruby is beautiful =)

Comment: Right, just don't name the argument :)

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if I understand your question correctly, but you can `yield` specific arguments to the block:

```
def loop
  [:a, :b, :c].each_with_index do |v, i|
    # you have access to both, v and i here
    yield v
  end
end

loop do |v, i|
  # only v is set here
  p v, i
end
```

Output:

```
:a
nil
:b
nil
:c
nil
```